# Fibonacci numbers program

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to write a program that displays the FIBONACCI NUMBERS, however, the numbers don't print out correctly and are always one number too high for what the Fibonacci number is meant to be, can anyone understand why?

This is the code i have:

```
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 1000:
      print(b, '', end='')
      a, b = b, a + b
```

(have to use those 4 lines of code)

And this is the output I get

1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597

and this is the output im looking for
0
1
2
4
7
12
20
33
54

the program should also start at 0 not 1

Answer (score 3):

Try printing `a` instead of `b`. `a` and `b` are the first two terms of the sequence, so if you want to print the first term you have to print `a`.

To get your desired output, instead of the usual fibbonacci sequence, you'll also need to increase `b` by one, every iteration:

```
a, b = b, (a + b + 1)
```

Comment: so like print(a, ' ' , end= ' ' )?

Comment: That gives the output of 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 , where as i thought the fibonacci was 0 1 2 4 7 12 20 33 54

Comment: @FawcettFawcett Looks like your output is correct but definition is wrong, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: My applogies, my lecturer has given us a assignment that gives the first few numbers of the sequence and says the out put should look like that

Comment: Looks like you just need to add 1 to `b` every iteration to get the sequence you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Printing 'a' instead of 'b' will solve your problem.
Try this code this would solve your problem.

```
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 1000:
    print(a, '', end='')
    a, b = b, a + b
```

while i traced your code i got,

- 1st iter : a=0,b=1 
  2nd iter : a=1,b=1 
  3rd iter : a=1,b=2 
  4th iter : a=2,b=3 
  5th iter : a=3,b=5 
  and continues..